# WebSphere cluster with members from same node

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-8

I have WebSphere ND version 8 with one Node under single profile.
For test purpose I need to create a cluster.
Can I create a cluster with all members from the same node ? (I do not want to create additional nodes.). will this work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes. You might find that having lots of JVMs on a single machine puts stress on the memory of the machine, but provided you have plenty of that (or set the max heap size smallish), you should be fine.